# Comparing a Particular Enum on an object

Tags: c#, enums

So how do I compare only the Number `enum` of a Card `object(card1)` to the Number `enum` of another Card `object(card2)`, when both objects have another `enum` Color?

```
public enum Number
{
  card_0,card_1
}
public enum Color
{
   Red
}
public Card(int fNum, int fCol)
{
   Number num = (Number)fNum;
   Color color = (Color)fCol;
}
```

For example, card1 is card_0 and Red and card2 is card_1 and Red. The 2 cards are in different lists one being the hand of a player and the other in the discard pile so how do I compare the `enum` of either just Number or Color so that it will know whether to accept the card into the discard pile or to reject it and say that it is not a playable card.

```
if(/* Compare card1 and card2 */)
{
  discardPile.Add(card1);
  hand.RemoveAt(/* Location of card1*/);
}
else
{
  /* do something */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Obviously you can write a method that compares just the number...

Comment: I think you should try to explain better your problem. For me, it's not clear at all.

Comment: Okay I am currently making a game that is similar to UNO, so I have to compare whether or not the card that i am about to discard has either the same number or the same color as the top of the discard pile, so i have decided to use enum to label the numbers and colors so how do i do the comparison?

Sounds better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a method to the `Card` class that does the comparison:

```
public bool DiscardOnTopAllowed(Card otherCard)
{
    bool allowed = false;
    if (Color == otherCard.Color)
       allowed = true;
    else if (Number == otherCard.Number)
       allowed = true;

    return allowed;
}
```

There are less verbose ways of writing that of course, but I tried to keep it super explicit since you are learning. Usage:

```
if (topCard.DiscardOnTopAllowed(selectedCard))
{
     //Discard is good!
}
```

Comment: What if the comparison is not done in the `Card` class?

Comment: @xwillflame The logic is the same, but obviously you need to reference both cards (instead of taking advantage of `this`). This seems like a reasonable behavior for a `Card` to have though.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question: How to compare enums? Let's assume you have two card objects `c1` and `c2`. To check if they have the same Color you do:

```
if (c1.Color == c2.Color)
{

}
```

and to compare card number you do:

```
if (c1.Number == c2.Number)
{

}
```

Also, I'd recommend changing the card implementation. If you are using enums then operate on enums and not on integers. The fact that `enum` inherits from `int` is only an implementation detail. But it's not a number. For instance, it doesn't support mathematical operation (which makes sense: what would be an expected result of `Color.Black + Color.Red`). So try not to mix up your enums with integers.

Comment: Um for clarification on my constructor, if it passes in 1,0 the card is given the enum of card_1 and Red right?

Comment: If you don't specify mapping in the definition of your enum then it will start from 0. So yes 1 and 0 will result in `card_1` and `Red`. But what I'm trying to say is to change the c-tor to `Card(Number num, Color col)`. Then you create a typ by `Card c = new Card(Number.card_0, Color.Red)` and you don't mix enums with integers.